# Infinite Multiple Column Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an infinite multiple column section. What I would like to happen is that make it infinite. I am already able to make multiple class but would prefer not to put i = 0 i =3 and so forth

```
$('.three-column-banner section').each(function(i) {
    if ( i === 0 || i === 3) {
       $(this).addClass('first one-third');  
    }
    else {

         $(this).addClass('one-third');  
    }
});
```

Comment: Unless you're creating infinite classes as well (obviously not possible), adding classes to make divisions won't work. You'll probably need to do the math in JS, and modify each object's style properties manually.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand the requirement. Do you mind explaining a bit more..

Comment: @Reddy I think he wants to divide an element into many  sections, to be decided at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help?

```
    $('.three-column-banner section').each(function(i) {
        if ( i % 3 === 0) {
           $(this).addClass('first one-third');  
        }
        else {        
             $(this).addClass('one-third');  
        }           
    });
```

set the class `first one-third` to all the sections at index 0,3,6,9... so on and remaining sections will have only `one-third`

**[Sample Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tpekhk7u/)**